# How not to open a window if the form fields are not filled?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this submit button on my form with a jQuery action to open a window depending on the users choice. However, I just want the window to open if the fields are filled. I have this code and I want to merge it with an `if`.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#chkveg').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });

  $('#btnget').click(function() {
    window.open($('#chkveg').val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://formmail.kinghost.net/formmail.cgi" method="POST">
  <input name="nome" type="text" class="nome" id="nome" required width="100%" placeholder="Nome:">
  <input name="cpf" type="text" class="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF:">
  <div style="clear:both"></div><br/>
  <input name="nascimento" type="text" class="nascimento" id="nascimento" placeholder="Data de nascimento:">
  <select id="chkveg">
    <option value="https://pag.ae/7ULKPL7TH">Associados Ancord + C.Dados = R$700,00</option>
    <option value="https://pag.ae/7ULKQ8Zm2">Associados Ancord = R$800,00</option>
    <option value="https://pag.ae/7ULKQLB9m">Associados Entidades Apoiadoras + C.Dados = R$800,00</option>
  </select>
  <input id="btnget" class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="INSCREVER-SE">
</form>
```

For exemple:

```
IF (#FORM).REQUIRED = TRUE {
  (#BUTTON).WINDOWOPEN
}
```

Thanks

Comment: if ($('#chkveg').val()) {
window.open($('#chkveg').val())
});

Comment: What validation are you using? I don't see any, but basically you would need to check if your form is valid in an if and then open the window if so.  I would also bind it to the form submit event rather than the button click event (a form can be submitted without clicking the button)

Comment: Exit the click handler if a field is empty: `if (!$('#nome').val()) return true;` before opening the window.

Comment: i didnt put validation because i dont know how is the better way to do it with jquery or using html5 required code

Comment: You can check with html5 and JavaScript/jQuery, however always you need to check on server side too. The old browsers doesn't understand HTML5, user can turn of the JS, but you can't go around the server.

Comment: I prefer to use jquery unobtrusive - https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery-validation-unobtrusive (with jquery validation) then you can use data attributes and also hook it into your js by doing things like `if ($('#formId').valid())`

Answer (score 1):

Because you using a submit button you will need to `return false`, in case if you don't want to do anything. Before that, you need also to check if your required field are empty or not. (i.e. `$(your field).val() === ""` then it's empty, if all you need have, then call the `window.open()` function.
Note: you can merge multiple fields for checking ie: `$(".your_field1, .your_field2, .your_field3").val() === ""` however this is an OR operation.

One possible solution:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#btnget').click(function() {
    let isEmpty = false;
    $('#data_form input,textarea,select').filter(':visible').each(function(i) {
      if ($(this).val() === "") {
        isEmpty = true;
        return false;
      }
    });
    
    if (isEmpty) {
      return false;
    }
    
    window.open($('#chkveg').val());
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="data_form" action="http://formmail.kinghost.net/formmail.cgi" method="POST">
  <input name="nome" type="text" class="nome" id="nome" required width="100%" placeholder="Nome:">
  <input name="cpf" type="text" class="cpf" id="cpf" placeholder="CPF:">
  <div style="clear:both"></div><br/>
  <input name="nascimento" type="text" class="nascimento" id="nascimento" placeholder="Data de nascimento:">
  <select id="chkveg">
    <option value="https://pag.ae/7ULKPL7TH">Associados Ancord + C.Dados = R$700,00</option>
    <option value="https://pag.ae/7ULKQ8Zm2">Associados Ancord = R$800,00</option>
    <option value="https://pag.ae/7ULKQLB9m">Associados Entidades Apoiadoras + C.Dados = R$800,00</option>
  </select>
  <input id="btnget" class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="INSCREVER-SE">
</form>
```

If you want only for the required fields, than use `filter('[required]:visible')` instead of `filter(':visible')`.

Comment: i tryed this but the window dont open http://jsfiddle.net/Chead/6n4pyuhv/1/

Comment: @Chead let's make it clear than, you want to open the window, only if the required field is not empty, right? And if it's empty do nothing. That jsfiddle which you lined is totally wrong.